# Update android room parent database together with children

Tags: android, android-room, android-database

In my android application, I have a parent and child database in a one-many relation, using a foreignkey to bind a column of the child database with an element of the parent.

The parent has columns

| period [acts as ID] | integer |
| --- | --- |
| classical | 1 |
| romantic | 2 |

and the child has

| parentName | firstname | lastname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| romantic | Gustav | Mahler |
| romantic | Richard | Wagner |
| classical | Wolfgang Amadeus | Mozart |

I want the user to be able to update the parent name. When the child is empty I can do this by having a method in the parent dao:

```
    @Query("UPDATE ParentTable SET period = :newPeriod WHERE period = :oldPeriod")
    void updateListName(String oldPeriod,String newPeriod);
```

But as soon as the child database becomes nonempty, this doesn't seem to work! How do I do this! Clearly, I also need all the child entities to be able to update.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the `@ForeignKey` annotation, you can use `onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE`,

- you may also want to use `onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE`

For more details you can refer to https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions

Comment: Great thanks! I didn't know about onUpdate, but I had already been using onDelete. Still learning sql and android room! Many thanks again.